# In-Band registeration configuration in ejabberd.yml to register from android

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, asmack

i am registering the account from android on ejabberd server but i am getting 403 auth error while creating account.

here is my ejabberd.yml. can anyone tell me where i am missing code

```
admin:
user:
- "xyz": "my-ip"

loopback:
ip:
- "127.0.0.0/8"
-"my-ip"

register:
    all: allow
trusted_network:
    all: allow
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution. In your configuration file, ejabberd.yml, you need:

```
mod_register:
  access_from: allow
  access: register
```